# Problems with WKWebview Custom Scheme redirect

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, wkwebview

I am using the following library to hook my app to internal OAuth2 authentication:  https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift

The library seems to prefer a `SFSafariViewController`, however I need to retain the ability to clear the cache and logout from the client so I am unable to use this.

I am trying to use a `WKWebview` instead and am unable to hook into the library's callback method after success. It seems as though the `WKWebview` is ignoring the custom scheme redirect. I never see the redirect happen in the following method:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)
```

I have tried subclassing WKURLSchemeHandler but it seems as though these methods never get called. This is how I am doing so:

```
let conf = WKWebViewConfiguration() conf.setURLSchemeHandler(CustomSchemeHandler(), forURLScheme: "customscheme")
let web = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: conf)
view.addSubview(web)
```

Also I am already allowing arbitrary loads in my `info.plist`.

Also the redirect and callback works successfully using a `UIWebview`, but I don't want to use this because it has been deprecated in iOS12.

Any ideas why WKWebview would be ignoring the redirect?

Comment: Do you have this line? `web.navigationDelegate = self`

Comment: yes. It calls the decidePolicyFor delegate method for the initial http request, but never gets called for the redirect which is a custom scheme

Comment: to see all redirects add observer `webView?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "URL", options: [.new, .old], context: nil)`

Comment: And then  `override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        
        if let newValue = change?[.newKey] as? Int, let oldValue = change?[.oldKey] as? Int, newValue != oldValue {
            //Value Changed
            print("NEW",change?[.newKey])
        } else {
            print("OLD",change?[.oldKey])
            
        }
    }`

Comment: Did you add url scheme to URL Types in project settings?

Comment: I went  ahead and added a logout mechanism to the OAuth service instead just so I could use SFSafariViewController. Thanks anyway!